# PL/SQL: I don't know how to properly insert data into a nested table of type object of 2 columns. Error:"Not enough values"

Tags: plsql

My code:

```
create or replace type imb_rec is object(cod number, job varchar2(20));
create or replace type tab_imbr is table of imb_rec;

alter table dept_ast add info tab_imbr;


declare
  v_imb tab_imbr := tab_imbr();
  i number:=10;
  v_rec imb_rec;
begin 

while i<=270 loop
v_imb.extend;
select employee_id, job_id bulk collect into v_imb
from emp_ast
where department_id=i;

update dept_ast
set info=v_imb
where department_id=i;

delete v_imb;

i:=i+10;
end loop;

for i in 1..dept_ast.count loop
dbms_output.put_line('Codul departmentului: '||dept_ast(i).department_id);
dbms_output.put_line('Angajatii: '||dept_ast(i).department_id);
for j in 1..dept_ast(i).info.count loop
dbms_output.put_line('Codul ang: '||dept_ast(i).info(j).cod||', job: '||dept_ast(i).info(j).job);
end loop;
end loop;

end;
/
```

I also have the error "must specify table name for nested table column or attribute" when I try to alter my dept_ast table by adding a new column of type nested table. I get the error "Not enough values" when I try to perform the select. I want to select, for each department (department_id increases by 10 each time) the employee id and job id for each employee for that department, and save those values in a variable of type nested table, save this table in my dept_ast table that has a column of this specific type, delete the values from the nested table so that I can save new values at the next iteration, the repeat. I don't know if my method is any good.

```
Error report:

ORA-06550: line 10, column 52:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 15, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "INFO": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 14, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 18, column 8:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 18, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 23, column 22:
PLS-00302: component 'COUNT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 23, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

My dept_ast table has the columns:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID   NUMBER(4,0)
DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
MANAGER_ID  NUMBER(6,0)
LOCATION_ID NUMBER(4,0)
```

And I want to add a new column to dept_ast of type nested table of object, and the object has 2 columns:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6,0)
JOB_ID  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
```

Basically, I want to have in my dept_ast table a new column that will be the collection of the employees that work in that specific department. Every line in dept_ast is information about a department.

Comment: Could you provide complete error stack and the pl/sql script that has been executed. Also could you describe  table dept_ast ?

Comment: I added the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the code by myself:

```
create or replace type imb_rec is object(cod number, job varchar2(20));
create or replace type tab_imbr is table of imb_rec;


alter table dept_ast add info tab_imbr nested table info store as info_t;

rollback;

set serveroutput on

select *
from dept_ast;

declare
  v_imb tab_imbr := tab_imbr();
  i number:=10;
  v_rec imb_rec;
  type code_dep is table of dept_ast.department_id%type;
  code_dep_t code_dep:=code_dep();
begin 
  select department_id 
  bulk collect into code_dep_t
  from dept_ast;
  
  while i<=270 loop
    v_imb.extend;
     
    from emp_ast
    where department_id=i;
    
    update dept_ast
    set info=v_imb
    where department_id=i;
    
    v_imb.delete;
    
    i:=i+10;
  end loop;
  
  for i in 1..code_dep_t.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Codul departmentului: '||code_dep_t(i));
    select imb_rec(employee_id, job_id)
    bulk collect into v_imb
    from emp_ast
    where department_id=code_dep_t(i);
    for j in 1..v_imb.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Codul ang: '||v_imb(j).cod||', job: '||v_imb(j).job);
    end loop;
    v_imb.delete;
  end loop;

end;
/
```

I can't just type `select employee_id, job_id bulk collect into v_imb`, because v_imb is nested table of type object of 2 columns, so I need a constructor for the 2 columns:
`select imb_rec(employee_id, job_id) bulk collect into v_imb`. Also I can't write
`for i in 1..dept_ast.count loop`, because dept_ast is just a table, not a nested table, so I need to select the values and save them in a collection before outputting them.